# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'-- React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, proguard, android-proguard

I have developed my application in react native. I want to minify and shrink my code. In order to achieve this I have enabled proguard and  added proguard based lines in build.gradle

Here's my code

> build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      //  minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
// buildTypes {
//     release {
//         minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
//         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
//     }
// }
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

}

Im getting this error.

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Im not sure where its going wrong. Please guide me so that I can resolve this issue.

Comment: are you solve this issue? cuz I Facing the same @Kartiikeya

Answer (score 1):

You probably get some warnings from ProGuard.
Try to enable setting `-i` when running your gradle build to see the warnings.

You can also test this hypothesis by adding `-ignorewarnings` to your ProGuard configuration. If the build succeeds afterwards if was due to the mentioned warnings.

Note: you should investigate these warnings and fix them if possible (some are harmless), otherwise your application might contain errors and will not function properly at runtime.